# Setting CSS class from data in ObservableArray

Tags: nativescript

I have an observable array that contains some info. I'm looking to dynamically change the class based on the data contained within the array. I've tried:

```
#js
var pageData = new Observable({
    locations: new ObservableArray([
        {location: 'OR1'},
        {location: 'OR2'},
        {location: 'OR3'},
        {location: 'WR1'},
        {location: 'PO1'}
     ]),
     surgeons: new ObservableArray([
        {surgeon: 'Dr. Pepper', selected_text: '', selected_class: ''},
        {surgeon: 'Dr. Scholls', selected_text: "\uf111", selected_class: 'font-awesome'}
    ])
    });

exports.loaded = function(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = pageData;
};


#xml
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" xmlns:statusBar="nativescript-statusbar"
  class="green" loaded="loaded">
<GridLayout orientation="vertical" columns="*" rows="2*,*,3*,*,5*,*">
    <Label text="mrn: 123456" row="0" class="h1" horizontalAlignment="center"/>
    <Label text="Surgeon"  class="h3" row="1"/>
    <ListView col="0" row="2" items="{{ surgeons }}" separatorColor="#58847D" class="margin-sides-10 rounded-corners-all">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <GridLayout orientation="vertical" columns="75,*" rows="*">
                <Label text="{{ selected_text }}" class="{{ selected_class}} black-text" col="0"/>
                <Label text="{{ surgeon }}" class="black-text" col="1"/>
            </GridLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Label text="Location"  class="h3" row="3"/>
    <ListView col="0" row="4" items="{{ locations }}" separatorColor="#58847D" class="margin-sides-10 rounded-corners-all">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <Label text="{{ location }}" class="black-text"/>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <Button text="Save" class="dark-grey margin-top-10" row="5" tap="save"/>

</GridLayout>
```

What is the best way to conditionally style individual components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the reason it isn't working is because you have a simple mistake in your XML.   Your xml needs to be:

```
<Label text="{{ selected_text }}" class="{{selected_class}}" col="0"/>
```

You cannot mix both observable code and non observable code in the same element property.  By you adding the "black-text" to the class property; then NativeScript would have treated it as a literal class named .{{selected_class}} and .black-text.

Comment: Ah, interesting. The error messages are a little cryptic. Given that you cannot mix, what's the best strategy to change the styling on a given component that may have several css classes? How would you do the equivalent in nativescript of jQuery's: $().removeClass().addClass()?

Comment: Well, I actually have written a cool plugin called NativeScript-Dom which offers element.classList.add, remove, toggle, etc.
The community plugin list is at http://plugins.nativescript.rocks